# Store value from model in a property

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an input field:

```
Name: <input ng-model="query"
             ng-change="vm.returnQuery(query)" 
             ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" />
```

And I want to return the inputvalue into a console.log

In my typescript class I have this field

```
_query: string;
```

These get/set properties:

```
get query() {
    return this._query
}

set query(value: string) {
    this._query = value;
}
```

And this function,

```
returnQuery(query) {
    console.log('Query: ' + this._query + ' ' + query);
}
```

When I enter a value like `something` into the input the console log returns:

> Query: undefined something

So how do I pass the value from the model through the get/set into the _query field?

Comment: you can use ng-change and call your function set to update _query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice to see more of your code, but let's expect that your controller (vm) is defined like this:

```
export class myController
{
    static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(protected $scope){
    }

    _query: string;
    get query() {
        return this._query
    }

    set query(value: string) {
        this._query = value;
    }   

    returnQuery(query) {
        console.log('Query: ' + this._query + ' ' + query);
    }
}
```

and if this controller is assigned to directive with settings

```
...
controller = myController;
controllerAs = "vm";
...
```

Then the issue with element snippet is missing **`vm`**

```
// instead of this
<input ng-model="query" 
    ng-change="vm.returnQuery(query)" 
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" />

// bind this way
<input ng-model="vm.query" 
    ng-change="vm.returnQuery(vm.query)" 
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" />
```

Comment: Looks good. You don't have to set `query` as a parameter though since data is passed through the get/set and not the parameter `query` of the function. Right?